# Type error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'

Tags: django

I have a table with a list of artists and a link to look at the artist's details.  I am getting this error when I click on the link:

Type error:  int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'

Can someone explain what is meant by a DeferredAttribute?  It looks like artistID is being recognized (because it goes to page http://127.0.0.1:8000/artist/1 when I click on the first artist), but not as an int.

Here's what I have:

models.py:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    artistID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False, unique=True)
    artistName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    artistNotes = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

artists.html:

```
{% block content %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Artist ID</th>
            <th>Artist Name</th>
        </tr>

        {% for artist in artists %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{artist.artistID}} </td>
                <td> {{artist.artistName}} </td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'artist_detail' artistID=artist.artistID %}"
                            title = "Get more information about this artist"> 
                            <img src = "static/images/info.png"></a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>    
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('artist/<int:artistID>', views.artist_detail, name='artist_detail'),
]
```

views.py:

```
def artist_detail(request, artistID):
    artist = get_object_or_404(Artist, artistID=Artist.artistID)
    return render(request, 'dtccArt/artist_detail.html', {'artist': artist})
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Remove the `Artist.` from `Artist.artistID`.

Comment: Awesome!  It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, you fetch the object with:

```
    artist = get_object_or_404(Artist, artistID=Artist.artistID)
```

But `Artist.artistID` is the modelfield, not the value you pass here in the view. The view has this parameter, since it is passed with the URL path, so you need to replace the value with:

```
def artist_detail(request, artistID):
    artist = get_object_or_404(Artist, artistID)
    return render(request, 'dtccArt/artist_detail.html', {'artist': artist})
```

The above view is however rather common, and might better be encapsulated in a class-based view: the [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview):

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class ArtistDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Artist
    template_name = 'dtccArt/artist_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'artist'

    def get_queryset():
        return self.queryset.filter(artistID=self.kwargs.get('artistID'))
```

and in the `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('artist/', views.ArtistDetailView.as_view(), name='artist_detail'),
]
```